# Color table rows and columns

Tags: tables, color

I have a table whose rows are set to alternate between white and gray using xcolor's `\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}`. I also want to highlight a column of that table, sos that it looks something like this:

[image: Alternating rows, highlighted column]

I tried using `\begin{tabular}{c>{\columncolor{_lblue!25}}cc}` to do this, but that just overwrites the color, blending it with white. Is there a way to blend the row and column colors so that it looks like the image? Maybe a variable that holds the background color so I can do something like `\columncolor{_lblue!25!\cellbgcolor}`?

Edit: What I have right now is

```latex
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!10}
\begin{tabular}[c>{\columncolor{blue}}cc]
    a & b & c \\
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 \\
    4 & 5 & 6 \\
    7 & 8 & 9
\end{tabular}
```

I've tried to use the transparency package to see I might be able to make the column color transparent in case it was overlaid instead of overwriting, but that makes the whole cell including text transparent. I don't know how I might go about alternating the color on each row while keeping track of the column color.

Comment: Could you please add a minimal example of what you tried so far?

Comment: not only fragment of code .... please extend it to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: TikZ's matrix library may be useful for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

unfortunately coloring of rows and columns in table doesn't has option for transparency of row colors (as far as i know). so it should be imitated by `\cellcolor` with appropriate color. for example like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand\ccg[1]{\cellcolor{gray!30!red!30}{#1}} % for cells in second column 
                                                   % and gray colored rows
\newcommand\ccw[1]{\cellcolor{red!15}{#1}}         % for cells in  second column 
                                                   % white colored rows

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!30}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        a   & \ccw{b}   & c     \\
        \hline
        1   & \ccg{2}   & 3     \\
        4   & \ccw{5}   & 6     \\
        7   & \ccg{8}   & 9     \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

One way that I have since figured out is to ditch `\rowcolors` completely. This lets you highlight rows and columns, shades alternating columns, and will blend colors for highlights. It might not be too pretty, but it works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \def\graybg{black!20!white}%
    \def\currowcolor{\graybg}%
    \newcolumntype{H}[1]{>{\cellcolor{\currowcolor!60!#1}}c} % Highlighted col
    \newcolumntype{C}{H{white}} % Normal col

    \newcommand{\rowalt}
            {%
            \ifdefstring{\oldcol}{NONE}%
                {%
                    \ifdefstring%
                        {\currowcolor}{\graybg}%
                        {\global\def\currowcolor{white}}%
                        {\global\def\currowcolor{\graybg}}%
                }%
                {%
                    \ifdefstring%
                        {\oldcol}{\graybg}%
                        {\global\def\currowcolor{white}}%
                        {\global\def\currowcolor{\graybg}}%
                    \global\def\oldcol{NONE}%
                }%
            }%

    % Overwrite the row color (while preserving shading and column colors)
    \newcommand{\owc}[1]%
        {%
            \global\let\oldcol\currowcolor%
            \global\def\currowcolor{\oldcol!50!#1}%
        }%

    \newenvironment{mytable}[1]
        {%
        \global\def\oldcol{NONE}%
        \def\currowcolor{\graybg}%
        \begin{tabular}{!\rowalt #1}%
        }%
        {%
        \end{tabular}%
        }%

    \begin{mytable}{CH{blue!50}CCC}
        a & b & c & d & e \\
        \hline
        1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
        4 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
        \owc{red}7 & 8 & 9 & 8 & 7 \\
        \owc{red}4 & 5 & 6 & 5 & 4 \\
        1 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1
    \end{mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` (≥ 6.18 2023-04-19).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ccc}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!10}{2,4}
  \columncolor[opacity=0.2]{blue}{2}
\Body
    a   & b   & c     \\ \hline
    1   & 2   & 3     \\
    4   & 5   & 6     \\
    7   & 8   & 9     \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]